# multiple counts of the same column SQL

Tags: count

currently using the following SQL to get multiple counts from the same column but my results are returning all the same

```
SELECT
act.OWNER_LOGIN,
COUNT(CASE WHEN act.X_ACTIVITY ='Call' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS YTD_Calls,
COUNT(CASE WHEN act.X_ACTIVITY ='Email' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS YTD_Email,
COUNT(CASE WHEN act.X_ACTIVITY ='Turret' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS YTD_Turret,
COUNT(CASE WHEN act.X_ACTIVITY ='Instant Message' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS YTD_Instant_Message
FROM S_EVT_ACT act WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE act.OWNER_LOGIN IN ('AC52710','AE34410')
```

**Results**

```
OWNER_LOGIN YTD_Calls   YTD_Email   YTD_Turret  YTD_Instant_Message
AC52710       421          421         421            421
AE34410       4279         4279        4279           4279
```

All these values should be different, not sure where im going wrong or if there are other ways to achieve what i want

Comment: You could also use count(case....then 1 end), which should give you the results you are looking for.

Comment: `COUNT()` count the number of rows, no matter whether value is 0 or 1.  `SUM()` on the other hand actually sum the value of the column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SUM(CASE )` not `COUNT(CASE )`

Count will give you a count of all the entries which is all the 0 and all the 1s

Sum will give you the total of the 1s but the 0s will esencially be ignored

Answer (score 0):

count will include all rows where the expression is not null, if you want to use `count` make sure your CASE expressions returns a NULL value for the cases that you don't want to count:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN act.X_ACTIVITY ='Call' THEN 1 end)
```

But not providing an ELSE, the CASE expression will return NULL for everything where the activity isn't Call.